# getting an error in discord.py v2.0 (cogs)

Tags: python, discord

I am trying to add cogs to my bot but It gives error(in repl.it):

this works without cogs

I also deleted the last discord.py(1.7.3)

and tried reinstalling the discord.py 2.0

this is on replit.com

that db and that secrets are replit specials also that doesnt effect the code in any ways

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/Dmoame/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 934, in _load_from_module_spec
    spec.loader.exec_module(lib)  # type: ignore
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/runner/Dmoame/cogs/Ticket.py", line 4, in <module>
    class Tickets(commands.Cog):
  File "/home/runner/Dmoame/cogs/Ticket.py", line 9, in Tickets
    async def hello(ctx):
  File "/home/runner/Dmoame/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 1748, in decorator
    return cls(func, name=name, **attrs)
  File "/home/runner/Dmoame/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 361, in __init__
    self.callback = func
  File "/home/runner/Dmoame/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 470, in callback
    self.params: Dict[str, Parameter] = get_signature_parameters(function, globalns)
  File "/home/runner/Dmoame/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 128, in get_signature_parameters
    raise TypeError(f'Command signature requires at least {required_params - 1} parameter(s)')
TypeError: Command signature requires at least 1 parameter(s)
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 31, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "/nix/store/2vm88xw7513h9pyjyafw32cps51b0ia1-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/nix/store/2vm88xw7513h9pyjyafw32cps51b0ia1-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "main.py", line 28, in main
    await load_extensions()
  File "main.py", line 19, in load_extensions
    await bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")
  File "/home/runner/Dmoame/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 1012, in load_extension
    await self._load_from_module_spec(spec, name)
  File "/home/runner/Dmoame/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 937, in _load_from_module_spec
    raise errors.ExtensionFailed(key, e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.Ticket' raised an error: TypeError: Command signature requires at least 1 parameter(s)
```

main.py:

```py
import os
from replit import db
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext import commands 

inte = discord.Intents.all()
 
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".", intents =inte)
try:
  print(db["servers"])
except:
  db["servers"] = {}
  

async def load_extensions():
    for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
        if filename.endswith(".py"):
            await bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")
        



Token = os.environ['Token']
async def main():
    async with bot:
        
        await load_extensions()
        await bot.start(Token)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Ticket.py in cogs folder

```py
import discord 
from discord.ext import commands
from replit import db
class Tickets(commands.Cog):
  def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot = bot
  
  @commands.command(name="ticket")
  async def hello(ctx):
    tks = discord.ui.Select(placeholder="Choose Your Help!",options=[discord.SelectOption(label="Support", emoji="", default=True), discord.SelectOption(label="Idea", emoji="")])
    acbtn = discord.ui.Button(label="Create Ticket", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, emoji="")
    async def choose(inter):
      try: 
        count = db["servers"][f"{ctx.message.guild.id}"]["ticket_count"] + 1
      except:
        db["servers"][f"{ctx.message.guild.id}"] = {"ticket_count":0}
        count = db["servers"][f"{ctx.message.guild.id}"]["ticket_count"] + 1
                                                   
        
      await inter.response.send_message(f"Ticket: {tks.values[0]}-{count}", ephemeral=True)
      db["servers"][f"{ctx.message.guild.id}"]["ticket_count"] += 1
      guild = ctx.message.guild
      await guild.create_text_channel(f"ticket: {tks.values[0]}-{count}")     
  
    async def change(inte):
      await inte.response.send_message(f"You changed the subject to {tks.values[0]}", ephemeral=True)
    tks.callback = change
    acbtn.callback = choose
    vitks = discord.ui.View()
    vitks.add_item(tks)
    vitks.add_item(acbtn)
    await ctx.send("Open A Ticket!", view=vitks)

async def setup(bot):
  await bot.add_cog(Tickets(bot))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to pass `Self` to the function

So instead of
`async def hello(ctx):`
use `async def hello(self, ctx):`